# How do you run a Pig script file via Java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I've been trying to get a java process to kick of a pig script via the PigServer. However every time the job kicks up reports 0%, lzo reports its processing the inputs and the job fails with no error other then PigStats reporting "Couldn't retrieve job."

Here is the code. 
Where report is a path to a pigscript and params is a HashMap of params to replace.

```
pig = new PigServer("mapreduce");
try {
    pig.registerScript(report, params);
    pig.store("patterns", "patterns");
} finally {
    pig.shutdown();
}
```

I have also tried replacing the store() with a STORE in the pig script, but has just yielded the same results.

Comment: So I have continued to dig into the issue. The code in question is being executed via a Mule 3 app, and I'm not 100% on this but I think the Mule Log4j implementation is interfering with the Hadoop logging system. Which I think is causing Hadoop to freak. I base this on the fact that after messing around with classpaths and instead of bundling Pig with the Mule App I classpathed to the local pig install I was able to actually get the job to submit to the JobTracker upon which I get a complaint about class missing. The class being the mule log4j implementation.

Comment: I tried registering the Jar with my pig script, but this just results in the Job getting submitted. However it just sits there in a pending states, but is not listed in the JobTracker. You have to hand enter the job to find it in the Tracker. Upon killing the job the JobTracker doesn't appear to notify the executing script of the failure(Termination).